# Timedate('now') with the following format :

Tags: pandas, datetime, type-conversion

I want to add to a column the current time to some cell in some columns. However, I want it to have the following format, and it now it takes a format I do not want:

**Desired format**: 2019-11-20 01:04:18 
**Current format**: 2019-11-20 01:04:18.426578

How do I remove this last part? The command I am running is the following one:

```
pd.to_datetime('now')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Timestamp.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html) by `S` for seconds:

```
print (pd.to_datetime('now'))
2019-12-04 12:54:49.072853

print (pd.to_datetime('now').floor('S'))
2019-12-04 12:54:49

print (pd.to_datetime('now').floor('S').tz_localize('Australia/Melbourne'))
2019-12-04 13:30:54+11:00
```

If datetimes are in column use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html):

```
df['dates'] = df['dates'].dt.floor('S')
```

Comment: Also an additional thing, I get the time of UK not the time of my timezone. Do you know how to fix it?  Thank you jezrael again for your help!

Comment: @Vasilis - Sorry, need `print (pd.to_datetime('now').floor('S').tz_localize('Australia/Melbourne'))
    2019-12-04 13:30:54+11:00`

Comment: Thank you, I get this error back        ValueError: time data Timestamp('2019-12-04 13:46:04-0100', tz='Etc/GMT+1') does not match format '%y-%m-%d' (match)

Comment: Sorry @jezrael what do you mean? I think it has to do with the format of the datetime I have.

Comment: @Vasilis - Do you think in column? Or `print (pd.to_datetime('now').floor('S').tz_localize('Australia/Melbourne'))` return error like in comment?

Comment: df['End-date-correct'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End-date-correct'], format='%y-%m-%d')

Comment: @Vasilis - only use `df['End-date-correct'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End-date-correct']')`

Comment: I do not print it exactly. This is what I am doing:         df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('End-date-correct')] = pd.to_datetime('now').floor('S').tz_localize('Australia/Melbourne')

Comment: By the way I am in GMT +1 hour

Comment: @Vasilis - So in column data are  like `2019-12-04 13:46:04-0100'` ?

Comment: sorry jezrael give me a minute.

Comment: The current output of the column:  2019-12-04 13:59:17   and I want to have 2019-12-04 14:59:17

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203601/discussion-between-jezrael-and-vasilis).

Comment: This is the type: End-date-correct : datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

x = datetime.now() # datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 4, 16, 8, 23, 22202)

x = x.replace(microsecond=0) # datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 4, 16, 8, 23)
```

See the microsecond part is gone. You can change anything with replace.

Here change the timezone :

```
from pytz import timezone
localtz = timezone('Australia/Melbourne')
x = localtz.localize(x)
```

Comment: Also an additional thing, I get the time of UK not the time of my timezone. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Edited. Try that one.

Comment: Thank you. I get this error back though: NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: :) what is x ? It is a name that I came up with. You should replace it with your own variable.